# Update APIs in Amazon API Gateway using aws-apigateway-swagger-importer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using the aws-apigateway-swagger-importer to import my API to AWS API_Gateway. I am using the following command to update my APIs

```
./aws-api-import.sh --update API_ID --deploy Stage_Name ~/file.yaml
```

In this way i am putting all the Resources and Method together. Now I just need to add one Resources with one Method to an existing Resources in the API list. If I just add one Resources with one Method in the file and run the above command then it adds that Resource and delete everything else.

So how can I add only one Resource with one Method in the existing API List ???

Comment: FYI: The importer now supports Swagger and RAML and has been renamed to aws-apigateway-importer (https://github.com/awslabs/aws-apigateway-importer)

Answer (score 2):

By "API" I assume you mean "method" or "resource" in API Gateway terminology. A single Swagger file contains the definition for a single API, containing multiple resources and methods.

You're correct in that the "--update" command will remove and add the resources/methods from the Swagger file. The Swagger file is considered the "source of truth" and any changes made through the console or elsewhere will be lost on update. I would suggest to contain all the details from your API in the Swagger file, and any changes made through the console or API should be ported back to the Swagger source.

Is there any specific reason why you need the importer to add only the new resource/method?

Comment: If I add new resource or method to the existing API list, Then it takes lot of time to import.

Comment: @LynAs this is expected as the importer needs to compare your existing API definition with the API in the API Gateway service. This requires multiple calls to the service to validate which components are present and which need to be created.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try to use 'SwaggerHub' to manage your APIs. 
It provides easy UI feature set to integrate with API Gateway. 
If you update your specific resource/method information on SwaggerHub, the change will be updated on API Gateway.

https://swaggerhub.com/

Thanks, 
Daniel.